# Question about the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading *New Foundations in Mathematics* by Garret Sobczyk.  NOTE: I have not studied number theory before, and I'm thinking maybe I should just skip this chapter, but let's see.

I'd just like some clarification:
So $h=p_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\cdot \cdot \cdot p_r^{m_r}$, where $p_i$ are distinct primes.  Let $h_i=\frac h {p_i^{m_i}}$.  Then by the Euclidean algorithm there exists some $b_i \in \Bbb Z$ such that $b_1h_1 + ... + b_rh_r = 1$ and $b_1h_1 + ... + b_rh_r \equiv 1\ mod(h)$.  Let $s_i=b_ih_i \in \Bbb Z_h$, then $s_1 +s_2 + ... s_r \equiv 1\ mod(h)$.  Then $s_i^2 \equiv s_i\ mod(h)$ and $s_is_j \equiv 0\ mod(h)$, $i \neq j$.  Then multiplying $c$ on both sides of the above equation yields: $cs_1 +cs_2 + ... cs_r \equiv c\ mod(h)$.  So far, so good.

But then he says:
[image]

I only know the *geometric* definition of projection, and I don't see how this relates to that, so I don't understand what he means by a projection onto $\Bbb Z_{p_i^{m_i}}$.  Also why should $c$ be equivalent to $c\ mod(p_i^{m_i})$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the language of projections adds much to the proof, but if we set $R = \mathbb{Z}/h\mathbb{Z},$ then we have written $1_{R} = s_{1} + s_{2} + \ldots + s_{r}$
(strictly speaking I should be writing $s_{i}+h\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $s_{i}).$ Not only dow we have $s_{i}^{2} = s_{i}$ (in $R$) for each $i,$ but we also $s_{i}s_{j} = 0$ in $R$ whenever $i \neq j.$ It follows that the ring $R$ decomposes as a direct sum of rings $ \bigoplus_{i=1}^{r} Rs_{i}$. The author is identifying the ring $Rs_{i}$ with $\mathbb{Z}/p^{m_{i}}\mathbb{Z}$ for each $i,$ which is legitimate since they are isomorphic rings, as we have $p^{m_{i}}s_{i} = 0$ in $R = \mathbb{Z}/h\mathbb{Z},$ but no smaller positive integer multiple of $s_{i}$ is zero in $R.$ The last point also explains why we can replace $cs_{i}$ by $c^{\prime}s_{i},$ where $c^{\prime}$ is the remainder of $c$ on division by $p^{m_{i}}.$